# iSeries SQL: current date not allowed when selecting records to create a table

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I need to create a materialized query table with records which have an attribute retrieved with a sub query on a second table, in order to get the most recent value of that attribute.
This question is very similar to the one discussed here:[Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group) except the following:

- inner sub query must compares second table's validity date to
  current_date (or CURDATE) not to another date field from primary table
- results are used to create a new materialized query table

Under these assumptions the SQL ends abnormally giving SQ20058 error, which can be eliminated in two ways:

- using a specific date instead of current_date, which makes the statement useless to my purposes
- adding

  ```
  disable query optimization
  ```

  to current settings at the end of the statement

  ```
  data initially deferred 
  refresh deferred        
  maintained by user
  ```

  which in turn disables query optimization made by iSeries V7R1 operating system.

To solve the problem, I tried to create a view with all records extracted by inner sub query, then issue a create table statement joining the view, so that to avoid sub query execution, but again materialized query table can't address a view which contains references to current date.

Do you know how can I compare records to current date when creating tables?
What am I missing?

Thank you

Example:
1) given sales table defined as:

```
create table sales (
item_id decimal(3, 0),
sale_date date,         
sale_qty decimal(7, 2)
)
```

with the following content:

```
ITEM_ID  SALE_DATE   SALE_QTY 
    1    2016-01-10     10,00 
    1    2016-02-10     10,00
    1    2016-03-10     10,00 
    2    2016-01-10      5,00 
    2    2016-02-10      5,00 
    2    2016-03-10      5,00
```

2) and depts table defined as:

```
create table depts (
item_id decimal(3, 0),
dept_from_date date,         
dept_id character(3)
)
```

with the following content:

```
ITEM_ID  DEPT_FROM_DATE  DEPT_ID
    1       2016-01-01     AAA  
    1       2016-03-01     BBB  
    2       2016-01-01     BBB  
    2       2016-02-01     CCC  
    2       2016-05-01     DDD  
    2       2016-12-01     EEE
```

3) that is the expected result:

```
select s.item_id, s.sale_date, s.sale_qty, d.dept_id
from sales s
left join depts d on d.item_id=s.item_id
and d.dept_from_date = (
select max(dept_from_date)
from depts x
where x.item_id = d.item_id and dept_from_date <= current_date)

  ITEM_ID  SALE_DATE   SALE_QTY   DEPT_ID
    1    2016-01-10     10,00     BBB  
    1    2016-02-10     10,00     BBB  
    1    2016-03-10     10,00     BBB  
    2    2016-01-10      5,00     DDD  
    2    2016-02-10      5,00     DDD  
    2    2016-03-10      5,00     DDD
```

where department id is flattened to its most recent value for BI purposes

4) when previous select statement is embedded in a create table statement like this:

```
create table sales2 as (
select s.item_id, s.sale_date, s.sale_qty, d.dept_id
from sales s
left join depts d on d.item_id=s.item_id
and d.dept_from_date = (
select max(dept_from_date)
from depts x
where x.item_id = d.item_id and dept_from_date <= current_date))
data initially deferred
refresh deferred       
maintained by user
```

it returns SQ20058 error.

Comment: Could you perhaps give us an example SQL of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I changed the question in order to add a complete example. Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that MQTs are not VIEWs; they are essentially TABLEs that store data that is the result of a query. Whether MAINTAINED BY USER or not, basing the data on some changing value practically defeats the purpose of "cached" data.

Comment: Thank you  user2338816, I know it. The choice between table and view is obliged because of performance response time, which in our case is much bigger using view instead of table due to the amount of records.

Comment: Then there's little reason not to use an actual table that you first populate simply by running your query from the MQT. Additional rows might be added at/after midnight only to add new rows by date. I'm not clear how a MQT would be better.

Comment: Probably I didn't understand you completely. BI MQT is refresh every night to collect data from about 15 PF/tables (actual table?) whose content may vary due to some delayed customer's processes. I mean, we cannot simply add new records, because even old ones may be changed.

Comment: The correct way to mark a question as resolved here on Stack Overflow is to accept the answer that you feel best answered the question for you, as you have done. You do not need to (nor *should* you) edit the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit

You can just add the "DISABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION" parameter to the end of your MQT. From the documentation all that it does is:

> Specifies that the materialized query table cannot be used for query
> optimization. The table can still be queried directly.
>
> [iSeries DB2 CREATE TABLE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzhctabl.htm)

So unless you want the system to maintain the MQT and the query optimizer to use the MQT for select statements on the original tables you can just specify the DISABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION parameter.

#### Original Answer

I am leaving this here in case of "data initially deferred refresh immediate" parameters. Specified for system maintained MQTs.

Seeing that MQTs without the "DISABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION" parameter does not allow you to use special registers:

> Subselect for materialized query table SALES2 not valid for reason code 8.
>
> 8 -- Refers to a special register or global variable.

There isn't any proper way of using CURRENT_DATE in the MQT's definition. So I would personally suggest that you rather just create a view based on your select statement.

That being said, here is a hack (or more like a chainsaw masacre) method that you could do:

Create a table that will store the current date:

```
CREATE TABLE cur_dat (cur_dat DATE)
INSERT INTO cur_dat VALUES(CURRENT DATE)
```

Then create a Job Schedule Entry that will update this table at midnight every night:

```
QSYS/ADDJOBSCDE JOB(UPD_CURDAT)
                CMD(RUNSQL SQL('UPDATE cur_dat SET cur_dat = CURRENT DATE') COMMIT(*NONE))
                FRQ(*WEEKLY)
                SCDDATE(*NONE)
                SCDDAY(*ALL)
                SCDTIME('00:00:00')
```

Lastly change your MQT definition to this:

```
CREATE TABLE sales2 AS (
SELECT s.item_id, s.sale_date, s.sale_qty, d.dept_id
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN depts d ON d.item_id = s.item_id
  AND d.dept_from_date = (SELECT MAX(x.dept_from_date)
    FROM depts x, cur_dat y
    WHERE x.item_id = d.item_id
      AND x.dept_from_date <= y.cur_dat)
)
data initially deferred refresh immediate
```

Comment: I give it a try. Thank you

Comment: What about "disable query optimization" parameter? Can you help me understanding why the presence of this parameter let current date being used in SQL statement? How much does it influence results?

Comment: I never even considered the "disable query optimization" parameter. That would be a much neater way of doing it. All that the parameter does is it prevents the query optimizer from considering this MQT for SELECT statements on the sales and depts tables. See this: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzhctabl.htm

Comment: Yes, I saw the same description on SQL Reference, but it doesn't say much to me. I will look for further information...

Comment: As regards "disable query optimization" option these links provide interesting information about it.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/dmmag/DMMag_2009_Issue3/DistributedDBA/
https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/6845.materialized-query-tables-mqts
Basically, query optimization influences which kind of select can be done.